# MeCabを用いたPythonの品詞抽出について

Tags: python, mecab

表題の通り、MeCabを用いたPythonでの品詞抽出に取り組んでいます。

しかしながら `TypeError: in method 'Tagger_parse', argument 2 of type 'char const *'` というエラーが出てしまいます。

環境は

- Python 3.7
- mecab-python-windows0.996.3

pycharmでのコーディングになります一身上の都合でネット環境がなく携帯からの質問になります故見にくいやもしれません。何ぞと至らぬ点がございますがご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
import sys
import MeCab
m = MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen")
datafile = open("乱文編集前データ\ロイヤルカナン.txt", 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
nouns = [
    sentence.split('')[0] for sentence in m.parse(datafile).splitlines
    if "名詞" in m.parse(datafile).split('')[4]
]
print(nouns)
datafile.close()
```

Comment: この質問文だけでは，回答者は「そのコードで何をしたいのか」がはっきりとはわかりません．また "乱文編集前データ\ロイヤルカナン.txt" なるファイルの中身がどうなっているのかもわかりません．できれば次回からは，そうした前提条件も明記するといいと思います．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのコードだと `datafile` に入っているのはファイルオブジェクトです．一方で，`MeCab.Tagger` の `parse()` 関数に渡すべきは文字列なのでエラーになります．

変数の命名からして「ファイルの中身をパースして，名詞のみを抜き出す」のが目的と思いますので，次のようにすればよいでしょう：

```
import sys
import MeCab

m = MeCab.Tagger("-Ochasen")
with open("test.txt", 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    s = f.read()

parse_result = [l.split('\t') for l in m.parse(s).splitlines()][:-1]
nouns = [w[0] for w in parse_result if w[3].startswith('名詞')]
print(nouns)
```

Comment: 質問文に不備があったのにもかかわらず非常に丁寧な回答痛み入ります。parse関数にテキストファイルなら渡しても大丈夫であると勘違いしていたようです。大変ご親切にしていただき誠に感謝し申し上げます